# What's the translation of "Youth Leadership Development Foundation"?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, phrase-request

I need a translation of this title ["Youth Leadership Development Foundation"](https://www.yldf.org/about) but I'm not sure if any of these titles is correct?

Especially I am struggling with a German term for *Youth Leadership*.

1. Jugendführung-Entwicklung-Stiftung
2. Entwicklungsjugendführung-Stiftung
3. Stiftung für Jugendführung und -Entwicklung
4. Stiftung für Entwicklungsjugendführung

The foundation also gives courses in English, in leadership skills, team management, time management, Making the decision, Persuasion and negotiation skills, Interpersonal skills, Communication skills, dialogues management, ICDL and more.

Comment: **Close voters** is this really a bulk translation request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, that [YLDF](https://www.yldf.org/about) is the right foundation

> Stiftung zur Entwicklung von Führungsqualitäten bei Jugendlichen

would be a well fitting translation.

But it is questionable, why the name of the foundation should be translated. Usually, one does not translate names of foundations or companies.

Comment: Why CW? There is nothing what would improve by a community editing  effort.